# error: can't perform indexing operations for <unknown type> type when sourcing

Tags: octave

With this code, saved as `test.m`

```
function test()
 x = 1;
endfunction
```

I get the following error message when sourcing it via `source(test.m)` in the GUI:

```
>> clear
>> source (test.m)
x =  1
error: can't perform indexing operations for <unknown type> type
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
>>
```

Calling the function test via `>> test` works fine, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

**Progress:**

calling just test, in the right dir seems to do it, but then what are we sourcing for?

Comment: there must be some other error in your code which you haven't shown above. Beside that, using `y = x>0` without arrayfun and the if...else part would be much easier, faster and more readable

Comment: I just copied it into a file. Pasting it  in `octave-cli` works without any complaints. However when I source it in `octave`  I still get the same error.

Comment: what is "when I source it in octave"? You've created a file foobar.m, pasted the lines in it an the you run `foobar` in the Octave GUI? Important here: run `foobar` and not `foobar.m`

Comment: I've rewritten the question (I was fixated on `arrayfun` causing the error) and detailed what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
source(test.m)
```

the interpreter tries to evaluate the "." subscript on the variable "test" (which is a function in your case) and then call `source` with the result.

What you want is to call the function `source` with the string "test.m" so you have to use quotes:

```
source ("test.m")
```

or don't use () in which case all arguments are passed as strings:

```
source test.m
```